# Linking data from Microsoft Access to ArcMap 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arccatalog, ms-access

I'm trying to link data in a Microsoft Access file to my work in ArcMap 10.1. 
Instructions online show people using the 'Customize' menu option and then selecting 'ArcCatalog' and from there selecting an add 'OLE' function; however, in the list of customize options I do not have an 'ArcCatalog' option to select.

Why might this be and what might I do in order to be able to link the Microsoft access data?

The data set is the HWSD world soils data base.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an Access table to ArcMap if you save the Access database as *.mdb, see [Save a copy of an .accdb file in the .mdb file format](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Save-an-Access-2010-database-in-an-earlier-file-format-efd3b0ca-e0da-44f9-a087-407376ddf211).

Then you can join them together if that is what you want, see [Joining attributes in one table to another](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/joining-attributes-in-one-table-to-another.htm)

Also good to know if you work with Access and ArcMap: [What is a personal geodatabase?](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/administer-file-gdbs/personal-geodatabases.htm):

> A personal geodatabase is a Microsoft Access database that can store,
>   query, and manage both spatial and nonspatial data.